# How to create a new column conditionally?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column called `id` to my pandas DataFrame. If the value of `id` is just a fixed number, then I can create a new column as follows:

```
id_value = 1
df.insert(0, 'id', id_value)
```

However, in my case I need to create batches of 3 rows, as follows:

```
id
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
...
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I don't think I understand. What do batches of rows have to do with inserting the column, and what is "conditional" about this?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Please see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create array by `np.arange` with integer division by `3`, so starting by `0`, if need custom first number add `id_value`:

```
id_value = 1
df.insert(0, 'id', np.arange(len(df)) // 3 + id_value)
```

If there is default index values also working:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(10, size=10)})

id_value = 1
df.insert(0, 'id', df.index // 3 + id_value)
print (df)
   id  a
0   1  2
1   1  8
2   1  5
3   2  3
4   2  1
5   2  1
6   3  9
7   3  2
8   3  7
9   4  5
```